# Problema con el bucle while en JAva

Tags: java, while, bucles

Intento ejecutar un código muy sencillo, simplemente quiero que el programa pida al usuario que introduzca sus hobbies hasta que el usuario introduzca 'done'. Entonces, el programa pasa a la siguiente parte. El problema aparece cuando introduzco 'done' pero el bucle sigue.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String>  arrayList1 = new ArrayList<String();
        String hobbies = " ";
        while (hobbies != "done"){
            System.out.println("Enter your hobbies: ");
            hobbies = scanner.nextLine();
            arrayList1.add(hobbies);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i<arrayList1.size();i++){
            System.out.println("Hobby #"+(i+1)+" : " + arrayList1.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira a ver que es lo que estas guardando en hobbies, seguramente sera algo parecido a `"done/n"`

Comment: Prueba while (!hobbies.equals("done")) para comparar string value

Comment: Un error clásico en Java es comparar Strings usando el operador `==`. Revisa estos enlaces de SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/8781554 y https://stackoverflow.com/q/767372/8781554

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al comparar **String** es recomendable usar  `.equals()` ya que al usar `!=, ==` se compara la referencia, basicamente si es el mismo objeto o no.

Aqui el cambiio:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    String hobbies = " ";

    while (!hobbies.equals("done"))
    {
        System.out.println("Enter your hobbies: ");
        hobbies = scanner.nextLine();
        arrayList1.add(hobbies);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList1.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Hobby #" + (i + 1) + " : " + arrayList1.get(i));
     }
   }
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Eso era! Muchas gracias por la ayuda y lo siento por la pregunta tan simple que he hecho, estoy solo empezando

Comment: No hay preguntas simples, te recomiendo que te ayudes corriendo en modo debug y poniendo breakpoints en partes del codigo donde tenes dudas; eso ayuda bastante a encontrar la solucion a estos pequenos problemas. Saludos

Comment: Voy a tener que informarme más en eso del debug y los breakpoints, pero ten por seguro que lo haré

Answer (score 1):

mira con este bucle, para que siempre te ejecute una primera vez y la comparacion de cadenas deberia ser con equals

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String>  arrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        String hobbies = " ";
        do{
            System.out.println("Enter your hobbies: ");
            hobbies = scanner.nextLine();
            arrayList1.add(hobbies);
        }while (!hobbies.equals("done");

    for (int i = 0; i<arrayList1.size();i++){
        System.out.println("Hobby #"+(i+1)+" : " + arrayList1.get(i));
    }
}
```

}

prueba con este y me dices, espero te sirva y la marques como valida By: JJ

Comment: Era lo que ha dicho el otro compañero por aquí: tenía que cambiar el "== " por "equals()". Muchas gracias por responder a mi pregunta

Comment: si, es verdad, solo es otra forma de garantizar la ejecucion, ya que Do WHile siempre se ejecuta una vez y luego pregunta